# Type '()' does not conform to protocol 'IntegerLiteralConvertible'

Tags: swift

```
func makeIncrementer() -> (Int -> Int) {
    func addOne(number: Int) -> Int {
        return 1 + number
    }
    return addOne
}
```

above is a simple example code for Function as first-class type in Swift
now, when i call the call the function in the following way:

```
var increment = makeIncrementer()
increment(7)
```

it perfectly gives the answer

But out of curiosity i tried the direct approach i.e.

```
makeIncrementer(7)  // error
```

and it gives an error

why is it so???
P.S. I am a beginner in Swift

Answer (score 3):

The call `makeIncrementer()` returns the function, so to call it you pass the parameter in a second set of parentheses:

```
makeIncrementer()(7)
```

The error message is given because Swift interprets `makeIncrementer(7)` as `7` being passed to `makeIncrementer` which doesn't take any parameters.  Hopefully Swift error messages are made more friendly in the future.  While technically correct, the error message given leads to a lot of confusion.

Comment: Joy, please accept my answer by clicking on the hollow check mark next to it to turn it green. Thanks.